# Need help splitting out a shared iPad

Tags: ipad, applications, apple-id

My partner and I have been sharing an iPad. All the apps were obtained using her AppleID, but I am the one using all the apps.

Now we bought a second iPad and I want all the apps to be on the new iPad, and removed from the old so she can start fresh.

I have my own AppleID. I also want these transferred apps to sync with my iPhone.

I really don't know where to start in setting up my new iPad to have all These apps on it, under my AppleID.  Is it even possible?

Comment: If the apps were bought using her Apple ID, then I’m fairly sure there isn’t a way to get them transferred to your Apple ID without merging the two.

Comment: All the apps is tied to your partner Apple ID. You can’t transfer or merge them to your own Apple ID. The only thing you can do is install the apps under your partner Apple ID, and then store the saved data to your iCloud accounts.

Comment: Sayzlim, How do you restore the apps on the second device using her AppleID to start and then save to MY iCloud, all on the same device?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a backup in iTunes of your old iPad and then restore the new iPad with that backup. When you turn on an iPad that is totally new, it askes if you want to restore from backup or start from "new". You want to restore from iTunes backup. 
[Guide for backup and restore in Itunes](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1766)

Once you have all your apps on the new iPad, you can manually delete or wipe the whole old iPad clean.
[Here are some useful informations about deleting/cleaning Apple i-devices](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2110)

Good luck and ask if you have any further problems.

Ps. You need to do a iTunes backup, because if you have alot of data (apps) there will not be space enough on your iCloud free 5GB standard subscription.

Comment: So should/can the 2nd iPad use BOTH AppleIDs then? Her's for all the legacy apps and mine for all the apps moving forward? How do you accomplish that? Are you avoiding restore from iCloud because of storage size concerns or to accomplish what we need?

Comment: I have never tried to work with two Apple IDs on one device, so I do not know if that works well. I have read that it is possible, but there could be some problems with backups and sycning properly. 
The reason why I recommend that you make backup in iTunes, is only because of storage issues. But if you have a paid iCloud plan with more than 5GB then maybe you have the storage needed for the backups :) I only backup my 16Gb iPhone in iCloud, other devices I own, I backup in iTunes because I don't have a paid iCloud (so I only have the free 5GB storage).

Comment: That's all the cloud storage we have too and I know it can't handle the restore. So if I restore everything to the new iPad, how do I proceed to make it MINE, and to make hers HERS.

Comment: Manually I think.. Delete all the Apps that are yours and then login with hers Apple ID once it is "cleaned" from your apps.